# RedirectToAction starts new session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, two-factor-authentication

I have a controller which logins in my user.  Assuming its an existing user and the password is correct i check if they have 2fa enabled.

**AccountControler login method**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, _configurationSettings.LockoutOnFailure);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, _configurationSettings.IsPersistent);
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Assuming the user does have 2fa enabled then i redirect them to the LoginWith2fa method.

```
  [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWith2fa(bool rememberMe, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Ensure the user has gone through the username & password screen first
        var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();

        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load two-factor authentication user.");
        }

        var model = new LoginWith2faViewModel { RememberMe = rememberMe };
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        return View(model);
    }
```

This is where my problem comes in var user = await `_signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();` always returns null.   I put a few break points in and it looks like its recaling my constructers both in ApplicationSignInManager and the AccountController.  There by giving me a new session.

SignInManager is registered as scoped in startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<long>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

How do you call RedirectToAction and retain the same session?

I have been following this project [Identity Server 4 Demo](https://github.com/rizamarhaban/IdentityServer4Demo)

**Update:  Comment about HttpContext**
[image]

Comment: The scoped request [lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) just applies to the current request. By using `RedirectToAction`, you're sending a 302 back to the browser, which then makes a *new* request to your new action, thereby creating a new scope.

Comment: `UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(...);` present in your solution?

Comment: @Mackan I don't think that's necessary for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @serpent5 Ahh, Core. I'm so behind. _goes back to identity 2_

Comment: Purely for diagnostics, have a look at the value returned from running `await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme)` in `LoginWith2fa` - Is that `null`? This is the first call essentially the first call made in `GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync`.

Comment: Is that a custom ApplicationSignInManager you have ? Because in the default signin manager the framework creates a different identity with a specialized cookie when you do  PasswordSignInAsync and 2FA is needed for the user. Do you do that as well in your implementation?

Comment: @serpent5 check the image i uploaded if that helps its not null

Comment: @MuqeetKhan yes its a custom signInManager i have some legacy stuff that i need to do in it.   I am digging around in the code for Identity now trying to figure out what cookie needs to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @muqeetkhan for giving me the hint.   Becouse i am using a custom SignInManager it needs to set the proper session cookies in order for the user data to be propagated to the next page.

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
    {

        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public ApplicationSignInManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<ApplicationSignInManager> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userEmail, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
        {
            if (UserManager == null)
                return SignInResult.Failed;
            var result = await new FindUserCommand(_logger, UserManager, userEmail, password, shouldLockout).Execute();

            if (result != SignInResult.TwoFactorRequired) return result;

            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(userEmail);
            return await SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(user, true);   // Required sets the session Cookie
        }
    }
```

Basically `SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(user, true);` needs to be called.