# Troubleshooting signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm new to ASP.Net and I've recently started a project, following some tutorials, making slow progress.

I'm stuck at the sign-in to the app. The app already connects to the local database and has a basic CRUD functionality for 'users' (Gebruikers in Dutch). I want to add 'admin' roles and whatnot, but first, I want a user to be able to log-in before being able to access the CRUD functionality.

So, I have put `[Authorize]` before the 'users' function in the controller and lo and behold, it gets correctly redirected to the login page. So far, so good.

The code also signs the user in correctly and two cookies are passed to the browser. However, the login page gets displayed again.

When I eliminate the `[Authorize]` tag, the code works as expected (without login). What am I missing?

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("Gebruikers");
    }
}

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = "")
    {
        var model = new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        // Check if valid
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        // Get the user
        var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync( userName: user.UserName, password: model.Password, isPersistent: model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        // Check if succeeded
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }

        // Valid and Succeeded
        switch (model.ReturnUrl)
        {
            case "/Users":
            case "/Gebruikers":
                model.ReturnUrl = "Gebruikers";
                break;
            default:
                model.ReturnUrl = "Home";
                break;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", model.ReturnUrl);
    }
}

public class GebruikersController : Controller
{
    // GET: Gebruikers
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Gebruikers.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

I can see some similarities to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754721/redirecttoaction-starts-new-session), but I don't think they're the same.

Comment: The most common cause for this is missing a call to `UseAuthentication` in `Startup.Configure`, or having it above where it needs to be. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602203/asp-net-core-identity-successful-login-redirecting-back-to-login-page/51608916#51608916) helps.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for putting me in the right direction. It was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59776432/11498) answer that did it. I had the order of auth and auth arse backwards. Now, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Net core 2.1* or higher on is built-in supports `GDPR` (General Data Protection Regulation).

and until you accept the cookie, cookie does not set in the browser.

add this following code to ignore `GDPR`

```cs
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;//<--NOTE THIS
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;//<--NOTE THIS
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Login";
});
```

Then check the Middlewares order should be like this

```cs
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Thanks. I had auth and auth in the wrong order in Startup.cs. Now, it works.